# filtering both the mongodb collection is taking lot of time to execute

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am trying to filter 2 collections both contain more than 30000 data. filtering the collection A is done quickly but based on the collection A value I am filtering the collection B which is taking lot of time but I need later data from collection B. I am able to filter but it's taking too much time to execute.

Here is the code

```
packageA.aggregate([
      { "$match": { "Family": { "$in": req.body.text } } },  //array of   
      {
        $lookup:
        {
          from: "lic",
          localField: "ProLic",
          foreignField: "ID",
          as: "subLic"
        }
      },
      {
        $project: {
          prodName: "$proName"
        }
      }
    ])
      .then(product => {   // from here its taking time to filter 
        var result = [];
        product.forEach(comp => {
          result.push(
            new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
              packageB.find({ "name": comp.proName})
                .sort({ "date": -1 })        //I need the latest update data
                .limit(1)
                .exec((err, docs) => {
                  if (err) return reject(err)
                  resolve(docs)
                })
            })
          )
        })
        Promise.all(result).then(ele => {
          var final = [];
          ele.forEach(ss => {
            if (ss[0]) {
              final.push(ss[0]);
            }
          })
          let fal = _.uniq(final, 'product_name')
          res.status(200).json({
            data: fal            //here is the final value
          })
        })
      })
```

is there a better way to reduce the execution time. please help me with this

Comment: what you are trying to do with this query ???

Comment: is there any mongodb-query so that is can filter the data?

Comment: you have to explain what is your requirement of this query.

Comment: You are  accessing the B collection in a loop, so it will take lots of time. Give sample A and B documents in json format, and explain what do you want to achieve by giving the expected output so that we can give you a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it would get delayed over there, You're iterating over an array & making a separate DB call for each `proName` - you can avoid all this network traffic by merging the below query with initial aggregate query thru `$lookup`. Have proper indexes on each field mentioned in query & let db take the rest of the effort, Also working on a data of 30K shouldn't be much of an issue with proper indexing.

```
packageB.find({ "name": comp.proName})
                .sort({ "date": -1 })        //I need the latest update data
                .limit(1)
```

Try this :

```
let result = await packageA.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "Family": { "$in": req.body.text } } },  
    {
        $lookup:
        {
            from: "lic",
            localField: "ProLic",
            foreignField: "ID",
            as: "subLic"
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            prodName: "$proName"
        }
    }, {
        $lookup:
        {
            from: "packageB",
            localField: "prodName",
            foreignField: "name",
            as: "packageBDocs"
        }
    }, { $unwind: '$packageBDocs' }, { $sort: { date: -1 } },
    { $group: { _id: '$_id', data: { $first: '$$ROOT' } } },
    { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: '$data' } }
])

Promise.all(result).then(ele => {
    var final = [];
    ele.forEach(ss => {
        if (ss[0]) {
            final.push(ss[0]);
        }
    })
    let fal = _.uniq(final, 'product_name')
    res.status(200).json({
        data: fal            //here is the final value
    })
})
    })
```

From this :`{ "name": comp.proName}`- Do you've multiple docs in `packageB` collection with same name but with different `date` ? If yes there are two options one is above query or else as an other option from the above query you could avoid all stages starting with `$unwind` if you believe your `date` field is a proper date that gets created while insertion of docs to `packageB` collection. As in `$lookup` stage `packageBDocs` array will have docs in the order matched docs inserted in `packageB` collection. So after `$lookup` stage you can just do `{$addFields : {packageBDocs: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$packageBDocs", -1 ] }}}` which will get lastest one document.